# Tagging failing tests in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure

After a pipeline has run in Azure DevOps (ADO) it is possible to see test passes and failures. I'd like to be able to tag failing tests with, ideally an external link i.e. Jira ticket ID to notify the team and others that the failure has been investigated.

I'm new to ADO but I can see there is a way of adding a tag to a test but I cannot figure out how to do it. Am I missing something? We only have basic Azure DevOps, no Azure Boards or Azure Test Plans.

I've tried the following

- Had a good look around the various test results screens
- Enabled/disabled various settings